# PowerBuilder 11.5 .NET DLL pbl

Tags: .net, powerbuilder, netmodules

I have converted a PowerBuilder application to 11.5 .NET. When it builds, it compiles into a DLL, an EXE and a bunch of “netmodule” files.  Are the netmodules necessary for deployment, or just part of some intermediate step?  Is there any way to get the compiler to build me one DLL for each pbl (PowerBuilder library)?

Answer (score 1):

.netmodules are intermediate files.  A collection of them creates an assembly.  Only an assembly can store executable code.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea if I can force the compiler to build me many dlls instead of just one huge one?

Comment: PB is getting obscure.  Try the user support group: http://www.isug.com/common/Index.html

Comment: .Net modules aren't really "intermediate" - they are a unit of type containment. Assemblies are formed when 1 or more modules are listed in a manifest. The manifest+modules is the assembly.